# MySQL nested CASE error I need help with?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, nested, case

What I am trying to do here is: IF the records in table todo as identified in $done have a value in the column recurinterval then THEN reset date_scheduled column ELSE just set status_id column to 6 for those records.

This is the error I get from mysql_error() ...

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE recurinterval != 0 AND recurinterval IS NOT NULL THEN SET date_sche' at line 2

How can I make this statement work?

```
UPDATE todo 
CASE recurinterval != 0 AND recurinterval IS NOT NULL THEN
SET date_scheduled = CASE recurunit
WHEN 'DAY' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval DAY)
WHEN 'WEEK' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval WEEK)
WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval MONTH)
WHEN 'YEAR' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval YEAR)
END
WHERE todo_id IN ($done) 
ELSE 
SET status_id = 6 WHERE todo_id IN ($done)
END
```

The following mySQL statement worked just fine before I revised like above.

```
UPDATE todo 
SET date_scheduled = CASE recurunit
WHEN 'DAY' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval DAY)
WHEN 'WEEK' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval WEEK)
WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval MONTH)
WHEN 'YEAR' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval YEAR)
END
WHERE todo_id IN ($done) 
AND recurinterval != 0 
AND recurinterval IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks to everybody, you were all great in trying to help me.
Looks like we all agree with wimvds. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you're trying to do something that afaik is impossible to do using just one query. You want to update 1 of 2 columns based on the value of your recurinterval field. So basically you should split it up into 2 queries, the first one will be the one you had ie.

```
UPDATE todo 
SET date_scheduled = CASE recurunit
WHEN 'DAY' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval DAY)
WHEN 'WEEK' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval WEEK)
WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval MONTH)
WHEN 'YEAR' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval YEAR)
END
WHERE todo_id IN ($done) 
AND recurinterval != 0 
AND recurinterval IS NOT NULL
```

And the second one will be for the other rows :

```
UPDATE todo 
SET status_id = 6
WHERE todo_id IN ($done) 
AND (recurinterval = 0 
OR recurinterval IS NULL)
```

If you run these queries (most likely you'll want to run them inside a transaction so you can rollback the changes if an error occurs during one of the queries) you should get the result you want.

Comment: What you suggest is what I'm doing now.  Because the "WHERE todo_id IN ($done)" is redundant, it seems to me that the two queries can be combined.  I couldn't figure out how to implement Nick Gorbikoff's suggestion of using an IF for flow control.  What do you think?

Comment: A flow control function to update one of 2 fields is AFAIK not possible with SQL. Yes, the WHERE todo_id IN ... is identical, but you're also filtering on recurinterval, and so you are in fact trying to update 2 different sets of records in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add 'WHEN' after the first CASE keyword.  So the beginning of the first line reads:

```
UPDATE todo CASE WHEN recurinterval !=0 AND ...
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I got this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN recurinterval != 0 AND recurinterval IS NOT NULL THEN SET date' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your first case in you modified statement `CASE recurinterval != 0 AND recurinterval IS NOT NULL THEN` should be actually an `IF`

Comment: I commented to wimvds answer about your suggestion.
I tested IF but received mysql_error(): Query was empty.

My code.

"UPDATE todo 
IF recurinterval != 0 AND recurinterval IS NOT NULL THEN
SET date_scheduled = CASE recurunit
WHEN 'DAY' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval DAY)
WHEN 'WEEK' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval WEEK)
WHEN 'MONTH' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval MONTH)
WHEN 'YEAR' THEN DATE_ADD(date_scheduled, INTERVAL recurinterval YEAR)
END
WHERE todo_id IN ($done) 
ELSE 
SET status_id = 6 WHERE todo_id IN ($done)
END IF";

Comment: Also with parenthesis like so
IF (recurinterval != 0 AND recurinterval IS NOT NULL) THEN . . .

I guess wimvds is correct in his response.

Comment: @AK - you are using the wrong IF statement. You should be using this: IF(...) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if  - which you confused with IF ... END IF http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html   - they are different IF statements - and have different context and use. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: OK I think that VMVDS's comment is right on the money cause it makes for cleaner code and is easier to read if another person needs to do it. And now that I took a look at your statement - I  think it's possible to do it with an IF (but your statement would be overblown beyond reason) - you trying to evaluate one field and set another - and IF is designed to update the field you are trying to set based on condition. So you could use an if statement to update date_scheduled but not status_id at the same time without running a subquery in your IF statement - so my vote is to stick with VMVDS's